# Как автоматически сохранять css файл после сохранения его Less файла? VS Code

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, less

У меня стоит плагин sftp, он автоматически загружает файлы сайта на хостинг после сохранений этих файлов. Так же я использую Less и мне нужно после сохранения его, заходить в CSS и сохранять еще и его, чтобы он отправился на хостинг и обновился. Как мне сделать автоматическое сохранение css файла, после того как он скомпилируется из Less.

Автосохранения у меня стоят, нужных параметров в VS Code для сохранения нескольких файлов сразу я не нашел